# Sets looping and operating in Python

Tags: python

How do I loop through two sets and make operations with each of the sets items. Or I can make them lists or tuple if necessary, I thought about sets since they don't have duplicates
However, I believe that is impossible...and it should be other way. Here's my code, is fairly explanatory, and it works until it reaches the sets, obviously...:

```
def p2():
    myPrimes = set()
    myPossiblePrimes= set()
    myDividersList= set()


    for x in range(2,11):
        for y in range(1,5):
            if x%y != 0:
                print (x,'does not equally divide with',y,'and I added ',x,'into the possible set')
                myPossiblePrimes.add(x)
                myDividersList.add(y)
                def f():
                    for a in range (myPossiblePrimes):
                        for b in range (myPossibleDividers):
                            if a%b == 0:
                                myPossiblePrimes.remove(x)
                                return[myPossiblePrimes]

                filter(f(), myPossiblePrimes)
                print ('checked')
    return[list(enumerate(myPossiblePrimes))]
```

Comment: That's correct, that you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for a in range (myPossiblePrimes):
```

Mixes up two kinds of `for` loop:

```
for item in iterable:

for index in range(integer): # or range(len(iterable))
```

You just need:

```
for a in myPossiblePrimes:
```

A few other issues:

1. A function for `filter` should take one argument (each item in the iterable being filtered) and `return` either `True` (keep item) or `False` (remove item).
2. `"myPossibleDividers" != "myDividersList"`
3. `filter(f(), myPossiblePrimes)` should be `filter(f, myPossiblePrimes)`

Comment: Yeah, but it still doesn't work, it just enumerates numbers from 2 to 10...thanks though, i will wait a little longer and then choose your answer

Comment: I have allowed myself to include my comment in your answer, hope it's all right. It was too little to post a new answer, and now yours seems complete.